# How to use an ipaddress instead of server name in a SQL query

Tags: sql-server, measurement-studio

How can I use an ipaddress instead of server name in a Sql Query for example.

```
SELECT * FROM [ipaddress].[databaseName].[dbo].[TableName]
```

Instead of `[serverName].[databaseName].[dbo].[TableName]` I wanted to get the info from a system of `xx.xx.xxx.xx` IP address.

Instead of serverName I want to get the data from this PC with MSSQL-server installed.

Comment: Maybe you use a connection string? Then you don't need to add this into your Querry
Maybe add a Port to the IP Adress

Comment: You would need to register the linked server with it's name being the IP address instead.

Comment: `sp_setnetname` allows you to use IP addresses for the "real" server name. If the IP address can vary per query, use `OPENROWSET` instead (you'll need to configure the server to allow ad-hoc queries for this).

Answer (score 0):

Register the server as a linked server and use the IP address as the linked server's server name.